# Understanding apache httpd access logs - 3 ips in one line

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, access-log

I have following strange behaviour of my access logs. 
The logs are configured like that:

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

Which I consider very standard. Most lines in my access log will start with two ip adresses:

```
144.76.159.234 123.123.123.123 - - [30/May/2014:18:05:07 +0200] "GET /page/foo.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1097 http://referer.com
```

The first one being mine, the second the ip of the client. However, from time to time I am getting a line with three adresses:

```
144.76.159.234 5.5.5.5, 123.123.123.123 - - [30/May/2014:18:05:07 +0200] "GET /page/foo.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1097 http://referer.com
```

Of course all addresses and urls are faked.

So what does it mean, when I see three addresses like that? The address in the middle is often a 10. subnet, which actually can't be ;-) This (three addresses in access log) happens approx 3 times a week.

My setup httpd -> virtualbox with httpd -> tomcat (but the access log is written by the second httpd).

Thanks in advance
Leon